# Temporary playlist in iTunes

Tags: itunes

Is there a way to have a queue in iTunes where you can add the songs you want to hear "on the fly"? Like a temporary playlist.

Comment: @bahamat Why should this be migrated, it is 100% valid for Super User.

Answer (score 1):

The party shuffle feature (recently renamed iTunes DJ) will allow you to customize the play list as it runs.

Answer (score 1):

You can drag and drop tunes onto iTunes DJ, and move them around within it. It will always top the list up to 100 tunes (or whatever setting up to this you choose), but you can delete tunes you don't want to hear and also restrict the choice to a particular folder.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a smart playlist and add songs to it based on your criteria. It can be modified at anytime, so when you want to change its contents, just change the stipulations. iTunes also has a pseudo temporary playlist: iTunes DJ. It isn't as customizable as a smart playlist, but it is pseudo-random nonetheless.

Comment: I can't really get this iTunes DJ, how does it pick which songs to include? Can't I just have a queue which starts empty on startup, I fill it with whatever _I_ feel like and it's gone when I close itunes?

Comment: iTunes DJ picks by default from your entire Music library. You can tell it to only choose songs from a genius mix or another playlist if you want. Unfortunately, you cannot add songs to it. It decides at random what songs are going to be in the playlist.

Answer (score 0):

Why could you not just create a playlist called 'temp', add songs to it, start playing it, then add more as you want. And when your done, delete it.

Comment: Of course I can, I just thought that the almighty itunes would provide something like a simple play queue, with maybe some specific options and shortcuts for convenience

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an empty playlist
2. Open iTunes DJ and select the empty playlist as its source
3. Find the songs you want to play in order and select "Add to iTunes DJ"
4. Repeat step 3 until you have all songs for your temporary playlist

You can also remove the songs immediatly after they are done playing, by clicking the "Settings..." button in iTunes DJ and choose "Display 0 recently played songs".